# How to assert for multiple actual values?

Tags: nunit

In nunit, suppose we have more than one actual values for the specific function to return, how should I frame the assert function ? Which function should I use ?

Ex:

```
int function(..) {
.
.
.
    a = some_operation();
    if (a == 0)
       result = 0;
    else if (a == some_predefined_value)
       result = 1;
    else if (a == some_predefined_value)
       result = 2;
    else
       correct_usage();

     return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may want to use [`CollectionAssert`](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=collectionAssert&r=2.5). This lets you verify that a value or set of values is contained within another.

```
CollectionAssert.Contains(new[] { 1, 2, 3 }, 2);
CollectionAssert.IsSubsetOf(new[] {1, 2 }, new[] {1, 2, 3, 4});
```

You may notice that the first method is checking for the second argument in the first IEnumerable and the second is asserting that the first argument (`IEnumerable`) is a subset of the second argument, also a `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 4):

Since NUnit 2.4, [the constraint model](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=constraintModel&r=2.6.4) has been available and it allows conjunctions and disjuntions. This allows more readable assertions for the same things.

Plus it includes many useful shortcuts, mostly in the `Is` and `Has` classes.

**Using fluent-style assertions**

```
// These are equivalent
Assert.That(function(), Is.EqualTo(0) | Is.EqualTo(1) | Is.EqualTo(2));
Assert.That(function(), Is.AtLeast(0) & Is.AtMost(3));
```